# Building a webshop frontend based on XML data in Symfony

Tags: xml, web-applications, symfony1, webshop

I'm faced with the nice task of building some kind of *almost* webshop in Symfony. *Almost* meaning that I won't need a shopping cart or secure connection or anything. Just a frontend to display products, categories and a link to the *real* shop. The data is provided by the shop as XML. As far as I know, I can request XML data specific to my needs and it will be served in real time by the shop server.

My question is this and I hope you don't mind me asking: What do you think is the smartest way to build this?

- read the entire xml OR
- read XMLs parted in my shop categories AND
- create php objects from the xml on request and rely on Symfony cache OR
- dump everything from the xml into MySQL
- A combination OR entire different approach ...???

I'm thankful for every hint!
Thanks,
thomas

Comment: Hmm ... since no one has any thoughts, I'll have a cronjob dump everything into a DB ...

Answer (score 0):

If this was my task ... I would have a task (on a schedule) to go get the XML and parse into a DB - the the front end would display the information from the DB. The downside of this is the update time between getting the XML each time - if thats acceptable this is the way to go ...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much logic you have in your own frontend, how many products you have and how often the data changes.

If the data changes quite often and/or you don't need much logic in your frontend, then creating a PHP wrapper for your XML will suffice. You can depend on/configure the symfony (view) cache for setting the lifetimes.

For more complex views (sorting, categories, etc...) you'll probably be faster with reading them into a separate database, because it can be queried a lot easier. Creating a task for this job, which you run as in a cron will keep the maintenance load low.